# Magento 2 + Product Meta title display in place of Product Name

Tags: magento2, page-title, magento2.2.8, meta

Facing some weird issue, Product Meta title display rather than product title or product name on the product detail page on the front end.

Magento version 2.2.8

Comment: check your custom extension because this not issue of magento

Comment: @RkRathod  it's core bug  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15501